# How to have a 3rd <div> to place directly under tallest of 2 other divs without nesting first 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have tried making a fiddle for this, but it's been too difficult to explain everything, so please bear with me:

I'm making an interactive Resume Generator, as some people want different information depending on the different jobs I am applying for.

Current live, but not widely published, page is [here](http://specialorange.org/ResumeBuilder/semantic.html).

General layout Im trying to do is [here](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1fhUg8R4mhBF3MgapuLOQl-kPQdvcKSPey6QXaGulVjU/edit).

So within the generated content Div, there are five sections.  I would like the first two to be side by side.  But since this page is dynamically generated (by the H1s, feel free to try it out and give feedback too), the height of "Business Approach" and "Snapshot"  can vary depending on what the user wants to view.   However, when the "snapshot" section's (right column within the generated content) is less than the left "Business Approach", the 3rd section comes in underneath it.   How do I set it not to do this.

One VERY POTENTIAL SCREW UP on my part: I have already tried wrapping the first two sections, but this breaks SOOOO much of my JQuery generation, I don't want to, (unless I absolutely have to) wrap them and then rewrite the Jquery statements.  First JS/JQuery project ever, and only about 2.5 weeks in, so constructive criticism is welcome.

Comment: you can add a `<div style="clear:both"></div>` after the 2nd section and see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, something like?

```
<div id="1" style="float: left; width: 50%; margin:0">left col</div>
<div id="2" style="float: left; width: 50%; margin:0">right col</div>
<div id="3" style="float: left; clear:left; width:100%; margin:0">col bottom 100% wide</div>
```

The `clear:left` on the last div does the trick

Comment: OK, so this works, BUT I also had to add thi clear:left to number 4 and 5.   While you have fixed my issue, you threw a wrench in my understanding of CSS.   I feel so uneducated.   Thanks,  helps a lot, I will get this eventually.

Comment: Just would like to add that, its not a good idea to use inline styles, please try to use class names and provide styles in stylesheet.

Comment: @Subhajit: indeed. Demonstration purposes only.

Comment: @Greet I can understand actually i wanted to inform Chris as he may think that its the best process.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code and found that you have given each section a individual class, as per your code `<section class="workexperience">` is the third section.

Just add this class to your css :-

```
.workexperience {
     clear:both;
}
```

The above css would make the third section to come down, and it would always come down no matter what is the height of the first to columns. try this and let me know.

Comment: can you add something like clear:all? or clear:"the remaining ones"?

Comment: nope clear property has only five values **clear:left, clear:right, clear:both, clear:none, clear:inherit**. **clear:both** clears all.

Answer (score 0):

Add `clear: both` to the section element called `workexperience`.

Comment: Looks like Subhajit beat me to it!

Answer (score 0):

The best practice say, dont use float, you can use display: inline-block, and vertical-align: top. This auto generate a responsive design.

example:

```
.fp .businessapproaches {
width: 74%;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}

.fp .snapshot {
width: 25%;
display: inline-block;
text-align: right;
vertical-align: top;
}

.fp .workexperience {
width:100%;
}
```

With this example you can see, how you can desing a template wihout float.

Comment: why is this better/convention/best practice?